# How do you create a pull request description with the GitHub hub cli tool?

Tags: github, command-line-interface, github-hub

I am doing this:

```
pull_request() {
  local url="$1"
  local title="$2"
  local message=$(cat <<-END
$title\n
\n
- [Story]($url)
  END
  )
  echo $message
  local pr_url=$(hub pull-request -m "$message")
  open $pr_url
}
```

I want this to be in the description:

```
- [Story](...url)
```

And the title to be some single-line thing. Instead the title is saying:

```
test\n \n - [Story](...url) END
```

When I run:

```
pull_request "...url" "test"
```

How do I set the description using the [hub](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html) tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not quoting `$message` in the *echo*-call, the output is shown on a single line. Use `echo "$message"` to preserve the newlines. It is not necessary to use `\n` since newlines are stored directly when using *Heredoc*. Actually, they are treated as normal text.

According to the [documentation](https://hub.github.com/hub-pull-request.1.html), *"The text up to the first blank line in the message is treated as the pull request title, and the rest is used as pull request description in Markdown format."* Because you have no blank line (remember `\n` are not interpreted as newlines), the description never starts and everything ends up in the title.

To fix this, remove the unnecessary `\n` and make sure there is a blank line after the title. Additionally, I suggest to use the `--browse` argument of *hub pull-request* to automatically open the PR in the browser. By wrapping the call to *hub* you might mask other output (like authentication) and don't end up with the URL in the variable in all cases.

*Here is a working script (`make-pr.sh`):*

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pull_request() {
  local url="$1"
  local title="$2"
  local message=$(cat <<-END
$title

- [Story]($url)
END
)
  echo "$message"
  hub pull-request --browse -m "$message"
}

pull_request "$@"
```

---

Example:

```sh
$ ./make-pr.sh "https://abc.tld" "A nice title"
A nice title

- [Story](https://abc.tld)
```

[image: screenshot]